# How to change segmentBar active Text color in NativeScript Angular 2 Mobile App

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to change text and border color of active segmentBarItem . Please check the attached Image.

```
<SegmentedBar class="m-5" #sb [items]="Items"      
    (selectedIndexChange)="onChange(sb.selectedIndex)" borderWidth="0"    
    borderColor="#c2d500" selectedBackgroundColor="green" 
    [items]="[{title: 'News'}, {title: 'Events'}, {title: 'Scan History'}]" 
    borderRadius="0">
</SegmentedBar>
```

I want to change the selectedColor to black. Now its default active segmentBar text color is white

[Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FgS2.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly your problem and post some code that you have tried?

Comment: My Code:

<SegmentedBar class="m-5" #sb [items]="Items" (selectedIndexChange)="onChange(sb.selectedIndex)" borderWidth="0" borderColor="#c2d500"  selectedBackgroundColor="green"   [items]="[{title: 'News'}, {title: 'Events'}, {title: 'Scan History'}]" borderRadius="0"></SegmentedBar> 

I want to change the selectedColor to black. Now its default active segmentBar text color is white.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that **Segmented bar** and **selectedbackgroundColor** will behave as the native components would. In this case for iOS, the selectedbackgroundColor will change the color of the tapped bar. However, for Android, the selectedbackgroundColor will only change the color of the underline for the tapped bar.